# James Munkres Elementary Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, soft-question

Can anyone who has the book give a quick opinion?
There are no reviews in any of the websites, and what's weird is the book is freaking expensive, but only 42 pages.Isn't this weird?I know rigorous texts can pack a lot into a small space, but all other linear algebra books are 400+ pages.Does anyone at least have the list of the book's contents?

Comment: Munkres and the Beatles were both getting started around 1964. Maybe you will be the first to write an Amazon review of the book.

Comment: You can get a lot into 42 pages... if it's printed in a 1pt font...

Comment: I have this book and it certainly is more than 42 pages. Could you provide an ISBN?